# Error running powerbuilder .net assembly in IIS wit ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, powerbuilder, powerbuilder-build-deploy, powerbuilder.net

i got a Powerbuilder (12.5) .net assembly application which dll generated is referenced by an ASP.NET MVC application.
Basically, ASP.NET call to PB assembly NVO function with some parameters, then PB retrieves data from DB (SQLServer) through a dataStore and then saves it as PDF, then returns the name of PDF file to ASP.NET MVC app and then Web application send PDF file to user for downloading.
In local PC it works nice.
but when i deploy into web server it fails:

```
Error: "Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation. Specify the ServiceNotification or DefaultDesktopOnly style to display a notification from a service application.
```

I have installed all dll from Runtime Packager.
I have sent all dll, xml and pbds that PB gnerate when project is deployed.
In IIS everything is rightly configured.
So id like to know if someone kwows anything about this error.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a role or feature that needs installed called desktop experience if I remember correctly.  This allows a service to have a desktop to run under otherwise it is a console app.  I ran into this when printing PDFs from a service.  The fonts were wrong and not set to what I set them to until I installed that feature.

It sounds like you already gave iis access to run on the server with full access to windows and file system.

John